# Does Socket.io work ? Been trying to make it work for 2 weeks now

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am new to `socket.io`. It sounds great but nothing works for me.

I have two file listed below: `app.js` and `index.html`. I have them both in the same directory. I `cd` to that directory and run:

```
node app.js
```

and then I go to my browser and visit `http://hostname:8888` and I get:

```
Cannot GET /
```

so I try `http://hostname:8888/index.html` and get:

```
Cannot GET /index.html
```

Why is it not working and why am I getting

```
npm ERR! invalid: socket.io-client@0.9.11
```

Please someone help. Thank you.

```
// app.js
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

server.listen(8888);
```

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-ca>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
npm ERR! invalid: socket.io-client@0.9.11 /home/username/node_modules/socket.io-client
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Yes, of course Socket.IO works.

Answer (score 0):

You write about your `app.js` and `index.html`:

> I have them both in the same directory.

But your code says:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Which basically means: *"my `index.html` file should be found in a directory named `public` which can be found in the same directory as `app.js`"*. So it's expecting this directory structure:

```
directory/app.js
directory/public/index.html
```

So either create an `public` directory and move your `index.html` there, or tell `express.static` to find it in the same directory as `app.js` like so:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

(Although, as @josh3736 points out in the comments, that introduces security issues so you don't want to use that solution in any production code! For testing purposes though, it's okay.)

As for your other problem, it's unclear what's causing that error. Please add a little more `npm` output.

However, you don't need to install the `socket.io-client` package if you're going to run the `socket.io` client from your browser, since it's already part of the `socket.io` package (the `-client` package is meant to be used to implement a client from Node itself).

Comment: I'd very strongly advise *against* `express.static(__dirname)` since you'd be making your application's  server-side source code (app.js) available to the public.

Comment: Does Socket.io require ports to be open up other than the one you are listening on?

Comment: @user1532576 no, it can piggyback on the HTTP port (`8888` in this case)